# Using a value as a key in Java properties file

Tags: java, properties, key

I know that it is possible to use the value of a key in a properties file can be used to reference its value like:

```
key1 = car
key2 = bike
vehicle = ${key1}
```

Is it possible to us the value of a property in a properties file as (part of) another *key*?

For instance,

```
key1 = car
key2 = bike
vehicle.${key1}.color = red
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties file is just for key-value pairs and you can't do such manipulations within a properties file. If you want you can pragmatically decide the key and put in properties file.

> Java don't have a way to do this within properties file till now.